# JavaScript function not doing what is supposes to

Tags: javascript, return

The function is not throwing the expected output when called. the return statement is not working.

I check line by line for a code mistake.

```
function checkDriverAge(age) {
  if(Number(age) < 18) {
    var x = "Sorry you are to yound to drive this car. Powering off";
    return x;
  } else if(Number(age) === 18) {
    var y = "Congratulations of your first year of driving. Enjoy de ride";
    return y;
  } else if(Number(age) > 18) {
    var z = "Powering On. Enjoy the ride!";
    return z;
  }
}

checkDriverAge(prompt("Input an age"));
```

The expected result is to output the string specified inside the respective "if" relative to the input age.

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with the return value? E.g.`alert(checkDriverAge(prompt("Input an age")))`  If that does not work look in the browsers Error Console.

Comment: The value returned by the function have no effect until its assigned to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

So, the way the code is written, the value coming out of `checkDriverAge(prompt("Input an age"));` isn't being assigned to anything.

Try assigning it to a variable, logging it out, or alerting the value.

```
console.log(checkDriverAge(prompt("Input an age")));
var x = checkDriverAge(prompt("Input an age"));
alert(checkDriverAge(prompt("Input an age")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything was working right, but you were just returning your message, you were never doing anything with it.  Adding `alert()` or `console.log()` will display your message.

I also tidied up your function a little bit. No reason to assign three different variables.

```js
function checkDriverAge(age) {
  let message;
  if (Number(age) < 18) {
    message = "Sorry you are to yound to drive this car. Powering off";
  } else if (Number(age) === 18) {
    message = "Congratulations of your first year of driving. Enjoy de ride";
  } else if (Number(age) > 18) {
    message = "Powering On. Enjoy the ride!";
  }

  return message;
}

alert(checkDriverAge(prompt("Input an age")));
```